# Laravel 5.4 server end & angular 2 front end .How to manage sessions and structure between both ends

Tags: rest, angular, laravel-5.4

How to manage laravel and angular along having full functionality
   both of framework and manage PHP sessions as well without using REST?

How will be the integration of both frameworks?
  How will be the structure? 
  Actually we need to develop Application with both frameworks.